# Best way to make fillets

Tags: modeling, bevel

I'm trying to model a casted water pump and need the edges to be blended (fillets?) as shown in the photo. I have tried creating the parts and joining them together via Boolean union. But the edges will not bevel. Is there a better way to achieve this?
 [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would help if you showed your current topology, but if I had to do it from the beginning I would do it this way: extrude the mesh from the torus, as it will preserve a coherent mesh, it will simplify the creation of the bevel.

[image]

Comment: A very simple and elegant solution. Thanks!